# Creating a log entry in logcat via adb?

Tags: adb, logging

Does anybody knows a possibility to add a log entry into the `logcat` `main` log?

I need to inject an log line with custom text into this log on arbitrary devices.

The main problem is that I can't just install an own app that does inject the log entries.
I need to create the log entry directly on adb.

Comment: Use the `log` commandline tool.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks that looks good. Do you know if `log` universally available or do I have to expect device that don't support this command?

Comment: `log` is a `toybox` applet, available since Android 8: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/3b051985b3c4787c8e323d41e2833c0278a13e20. For older releases you can port the binary. It's very minimalistic.